# How to troubleshoot a hanged procedure in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I've a very odd hanging procedure that is done when doing it in a certain sequence only.

For example:
Sequence-1 (Hanging):
1-execute procedure-x
2-execute procedure-y

Sequence-2 (Not-Hanging):
1-execute procedure-x
2-disconnect from session or opening a new session
3-execute procedure-y

How can I dig down to see what is blocking a certain sequence of execution ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [explicit locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html) to preserve the order of execution. Advisory locks may help you even to synchronize transactions that working on a different tables.

Comment: What are these procedures doing? A session cannot block with itself, so there must be something else going on. Check `pg_locks` to see if it is truly locked or just hogging the CPU.